# Always Make Scrollbar Visible in UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I would like to show the Scroll bar indicators always visible so that the user knows there is something to scroll. So I have gone through this [link](http://www.developers-life.com/scrollview-with-scrolls-indicators-which-are-shown-all-the-time.html) . It is working fine but At the very first time it is not showing the Scroll bar indicator . i.e Whenever ViewDidLoad is calling the scrollview not showing the scrollbarindicator, but after scrolling the scrollview few pixel it always showing the Scroll bar indicators  . Any ideas or suggestions could be very greatful . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the code in ViewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad.

Comment: @Tendulkar Glad it helped, Mark the answer as correct for other users.

Comment: I will do it after 5 mins When I click on correct answer it is saying that you can mark it after 5 mins. I will do it dude .